# How to wait for API response

Tags: api, response

I'm trying to make my API request wait for API response, i did this:

```
export async function foldercreator(language,date){
```

const paths = ["" ,"/" + language , "/" + language + "/" + "/kanban","/" + language + "/" + "/LavagnaFornitore", "/" + language + "/" + "/LavagnaPianificatore"];

```
for(let i=0; i<paths.length; i++){
    var request = await require('request');
    var options = {
        'method': 'MKCOL',
        'url': "****"
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Basic *******',
        },
    };
    await request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(response.body);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have `async` function

Comment: Ia have it, here u cant see it, but im using this:
export async function foldercreator(language,date){

Comment: How i can help you if i can't see it please show us  enough amount of code so we can help you

Comment: Idk why it looks this way but u can see the whole code now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).